# "if windows.width less than" doesn't work

Tags: jquery, if-statement, window, width

i have this code and i'm trying to make it work.

Basically, if the screen is less than 480px wide, is resizes the height of the #page div and centers it vertically. Else, if the width is wider, is just centers it vertically.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var wwidth = jQuery(window).innerWidth();
   if (wwidth <= 480) {
     function thirty_pc() {
     var height = jQuery(window).innerHeight();
     var thirtypc = ((95 * height) / 100) - 40;
     var topmargin = (height - thirtypc - 40) / 2;
     thirtypc = parseInt(thirtypc) + 'px';
     topmargin = parseInt(topmargin) + 'px';
     jQuery("#page").css('height',thirtypc);
     jQuery("#page").css('margin-top',topmargin);
     }

    thirty_pc();
    jQuery(window).bind('resize', thirty_pc);

   } else {
     function thirty_pc() {
     var height = jQuery(window).innerHeight();
     var pageheight = jQuery("#page").height()
     var thirtypc = (height - pageheight - 60);
     var topmargin = (thirtypc / 2);
     thirtypc = parseInt(thirtypc) + 'px';
     topmargin = parseInt(topmargin) + 'px';
     jQuery("#page").css('margin-top',topmargin);
     }

    thirty_pc();
    jQuery(window).bind('resize', thirty_pc);
}});
```

However, it doesn't fire when windows.width is less than 480px... cannot understand why.

Comment: What's wrong with just using window.innerWidth?

Comment: changed, it does not work either. Just the "else" statement is applied, as if the innerWidth was wider than.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind the resize event before.

And your code is a mess. Please tidy it up, so you can see the bugs faster.

Try this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  function thirty_pc() {
    var wwidth = jQuery(window).width();
    if (wwidth <= 480) {
      var height = jQuery(window).innerHeight();
      var thirtypc = ((95 * height) / 100) - 40;
      var topmargin = (height - thirtypc - 40) / 2;
      thirtypc = parseInt(thirtypc) + 'px';
      topmargin = parseInt(topmargin) + 'px';
      jQuery("#page").css('height',thirtypc);
      jQuery("#page").css('margin-top',topmargin);
      console.log('under 480px');
     } else {
      var height = jQuery(window).innerHeight();
      var pageheight = jQuery("#page").height();
      var thirtypc = (height - pageheight - 60);
      var topmargin = (thirtypc / 2);
      thirtypc = parseInt(thirtypc) + 'px';
      topmargin = parseInt(topmargin) + 'px';
      jQuery("#page").css('margin-top',topmargin);
      console.log('over 480px');
    }
  }

  jQuery(window).bind('resize', thirty_pc);
});
```

Comment: As it is, it works just if you resize the windows, works better with few changes. Posted down.

Comment: When this code helps you with your question, it would be nice, if you set it as correct answer, please. And what did you change? You've just removed the console.log and the indents... And you set the wwidth outside of the function. So you can't get the recent window width, when resizing the browser.

Comment: I think you edited it while i was trying already, will update later :) when i used it, it was missing a } and other minor syntax changes, such as the missing call to thirty_pc(); before (window).bind (without that call it works when u resize the windows only, and not on document ready)

Answer (score 0):

The code posted by roNn23 works well with few (minor) changes, as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   function thirty_pc() {
   var wwidth = jQuery(window).width();
      if (wwidth <= 480) {
         var height = jQuery(window).height();
         var thirtypc = ((95 * height) / 100) - 40;
         var topmargin = (height - thirtypc - 40) / 2;
         thirtypc = parseInt(thirtypc) + 'px';
         topmargin = parseInt(topmargin) + 'px';
         jQuery("#page").css('height',thirtypc);
         jQuery("#page").css('margin-top',topmargin);
      } else {
         var height = jQuery(window).innerHeight();
         var pageheight = jQuery("#page").height()
         var thirtypc = (height - pageheight - 60);
         var topmargin = (thirtypc / 2);
         thirtypc = parseInt(thirtypc) + 'px';
         topmargin = parseInt(topmargin) + 'px';
         jQuery("#page").css('margin-top',topmargin);
         }
      }
thirty_pc();    
jQuery(window).bind('resize', thirty_pc);
});
```

Now i'm trying to remove a little of vertical scroll that occurs on my smartphone!

Comment: Just to let you know: the -40 and -60 values are there to compensate for padding on CSS ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will fire the window resize event. Use window.innerWidth instead of jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', moveDiv);
});
function moveDiv() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 481) {
        //do something
    }
}
```